# On subring $R\subseteq S$ such that the inclusion map $i: R\to S$ splits as an $R$-module map

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, direct-sum

Let $R\subseteq S$ be commutative rings in the sense that $R$ is a subring of $S$ with the same unity. So canonically, $S$ has an $R$-module structure.  We say that the inclusion map $i: R\to S$ splits as a map of $R$-modules iff there exists an $R$-module map $f: S\to R$ such that $f\circ i=id_R$ (i.e. $f(r)=r, \forall r\in R$). Since $f$ is an $R$-module map so $f(r)=r,\forall r\in R$ is same as saying $f(1)=1$.

Now my question is: if for some $R$-module $M$, we have an isomorphism of $R$-modules $S\cong R\oplus M$, then is it true that the inclusion map $i:R\to S$ splits ?

(Note that I'm not specifying anything about how the isomorphism $S\cong R\oplus M$ looks like ...)

My try: If $\phi : S\to R\oplus M$ is the isomorphism, then the natural candidate for $f: S\to R$ is $f=\pi_1\circ \phi$ , where $\pi_1:R\oplus M\to R$ is the canonical first coordinate surjection. But I'm unable to see why $f(1)=1$ with this choice of $f$ .

Please help.

Added Notes: the existence of an $R$-linear isomorphism $\phi: S\to R\oplus M$ gives rise to an induced exact sequence $0\to R\xrightarrow{\phi \circ i} R\oplus M \xrightarrow{\pi_2} M\to 0$ . Now this sequence splits if there exists an $R$-linear map $f:S\to R$ with $f(1)=1$ i.e. if $R$ is a direct summand of $S$ in our sense . Indeed if $f:S\to R$ is $R$-linear with $f(1)=1$, then $f\circ \phi^{-1}: R\oplus M\to R$ gives the required map for splitting the above sequence.

Comment: If your ring homomorphisms preserve unity, then $i(1_R) = (1_R, 1_M)$, right? Even if it's a different copy of $R$, this should still give $f(1_S)=1_R$ (possibly after composing with an isomorphism between the weirdly embedded $R$ and the left summand $R$). I think the bigger issue is seeing why $f$ is $R$ linear with the $R$ module structure coming from this weird embedding.

Comment: Unless you mean $S \cong R \oplus M$ as $R$-modules, in which case my comment might just answer the question?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: please read my question carefully ... $i$ is the inclusion map , $R$ and $S$ have the same unity , $M$ is an $R$-module, so I have no idea what you mean by $1_M$ and I have no idea what you are trying to point out by your second comment ... also just to be sure you understand it correctly,  there exists an $R$-module isomorphism $\phi: S\to R\oplus M$ ... in no way am I saying (and it wouldn't even make sense) $S=R\oplus M$ ...

Comment: $i$ will split in the category of $R$-modules by the Splitting lemma and your map $f$ will work. Is the question whether $f$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: But isn't your inclusion the natural map $i:R\to R\oplus M$? If you consider the two exact sequences with $0\to R\to S$ on the top, $0\to R\to R\oplus M$ on the bottom, and the isomorphisms between the two, then don't you have a split map on the bottom and can then construct a split map on the top?

Comment: @Zeek: the diagram you have in mind may not commute : if $i: R\to S$ is the inclusion ($i(r)=r,\forall r\in R$)  and $\phi: S\to R\oplus M$ is an $R$-module isomorphism (and I do not know anything about the structure of $\phi$ ), then it is NOT necessarily true that $\phi\circ i: R\to R\oplus M$ is given by $r\to (r,0)$ ...

Comment: Your question may be translated as follows: assume that there exists a surjective $R$-linear map $\beta:S\to R$. Then there exists a (necessarily surjective) linear map $\gamma: S\to R$ such that $\gamma(1)=1$. Peersonnally, i don't see immediately why it should be true...

Comment: Another comment: if you want $R$ to be a direct summand, then $R$ needs to be a pure submodule of $S$ (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_submodule)  (wrt to $i$). It is not totally clear to me if the condition $S\simeq R\times M$ implies that $R$ is pure (it implies purity of the image of $R\to R\times M\to S$, though)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

Let $S=\mathbb{Z}[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2},\sqrt{2}]$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$.
One may show that $S=R\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\oplus (\sqrt{-3}R+\sqrt{2}R)$.

This can be done (rather tediously) by hand, or you can notice that $S$ is the ring of integers of  $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6},\sqrt{-3})$ and $R$ is the ring of integers of $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$, and apply theorem 3.1 of  https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf with $d=2$ and $q=3$.

If you want a quicker argument, you could say that $R$ is a Dedekind ring (it is the ring of integrs of $F$), and $S$ is a finitely generated  $R$-module (since it is already finitely generated of $\mathbb{Z}$) which is torsion free. It is then well-known that such a module is isomorphic to $R^{k-1}\times I$, where $I$ is a nonzero ideal of $R$, where $k$  is the rank (it is known that a torsion free finitely generate $R$-module is a projective of constant rank, so the rank is defined.)

So in our case, whichever method you choose, you find that  $S\simeq R\times M$, for some $R$-module $M$.

It remains to show that $R$ is not a direct summand of $S$, which is equivalent to say that there is no $R$-linear map $f:S\to R$ such that $f(1)=1$. Note that such a map is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear since it is $R$-linear.
We are going to exploit the fact that $1,\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}, \sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $S$.

Let $a=f(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}),b=f(\sqrt{2}),c=f(\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}).$

We have $\sqrt{-6}\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{-6}-\sqrt{18}}{2}=\sqrt{2}\dfrac{\sqrt{-3}-3}{2}=\sqrt{2}(-2+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})$, so $$\sqrt{-6}a=-2b+c. \ \  (1)$$
We have $\sqrt{-6}\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{-3}=2\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}-1$, so $$\sqrt{-6}b=2a-1.\ \  (2)$$
We have $\sqrt{-6}\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}(-2+\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})=-4+2\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, so $$\sqrt{-6}c=-4+2a.\ \  (3)$$
Multipliying $(1)$ by $\sqrt{-6}$ and using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get $-6a=-2(2a-1)-4+2a$, that is $a=\dfrac{1}{2}\notin R$, and $f$ does not exist.

Comment: i've rechecked my computations, and i still find a contradiction (hopefully, my computations are correct now). The link to the paper provided in the topic  you cite  is about a different question.

Comment: Also, you've denoted the value of your $a$ wrong I believe ...

Comment: yes, just a misprint. Nevertheless, unless my computations are wrong again (still possible, it's late here), i've proved that $S\simeq R\times M$ but $R$ is not an indirect internal summand....

Comment: So I kept thinking, and I think I've got a proof for my proposition and now I'm not sure what's happening... Here's my proof: Let $\phi : S\to R\oplus M$ be the $R$-linear isomorphism. Let $a\in S$ be such that $\phi (a)=(1,0)$. Let $\pi_1: R\oplus M\to R$ be the canonical $R$-linear projection. Define  $f: S\to R$ as $f(y)=\pi_1(\phi(ay)),\forall y\in S$. Then $f$ is $R$-linear and $f(1)=1$ ... where am I going wrong ?

Comment: So actually, now when I think about your proof of counterexample, you mention that $S\cong R^{k-1}\oplus I$ where $k$ is the rank of $S$ over $R$ , now it might happen that $k=1$ in which case $S $ need not be isomorphic to $R\oplus M$ ...

Comment: Did you get time to think on my comment ?